# Possible to query a custom post type that matches two categories?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this. From digging around in the docs I can't seem to get this to work, but it seems possible? I've tried category__and (seems to be the answer?) as well as utilizing a taxonomy => AND and then trying to query all posts, but neither seems to return anything. Thanks!

```
<?php $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'our_team' ,
                                'orderby' => 'title' ,
                                'order' => 'ASC' ,
                                'posts_per_page' => 50,
                                'category__and' => array('462','473'),
                                'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                                'post_parent' => $parent
                           ); ?>
                           <?php query_posts($args); ?>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is using a custom taxonomy, you can query the custom terms using 'tax_query'.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'our-team',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'operator' => 'IN', //or AND if it needs to match both terms
            'terms' => array('some-term', 'another-term')
        ),
    ),
);
$your_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Just want to leave this note for anyone struggling in the future: the above answer is very helpful, but if you're trying to look for custom post types that only match two categories (ie overlap with 2, which is what I was struggling to find) - the above will work if you use  'operator' => 'AND' -- so 'IN' pulls in anything of that post type that matches either category (if 'category' is your desired taxonomy) and using 'AND' pulls in any custom post types that match both queried categories.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a little comment in the code next to the operator.